# MongoDb Automatic Backup NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mean-stack

I am working on a project that requires MongoDb backup after a certain period of time. The project is being built over MongoDB, Express as backend technologies. 
Also, How would it be restored on the server? I am a beginner in MEAN Stack but according to my knowledge, I might make a script on the server and execute it on a given time to generate a backup. Kindly help me with writing the script to perform the tasks mentioned above.

Comment: I wrote one backup script in python for automatic backup of mongo db and it pushes that backup to s3. If you want then I can give it to you.

Comment: Um, I needed a javascript script since my server is set up on NodeJS

Comment: @iit2011081 can you please, share backup script in python. I am having with an issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66241860/documentdb-backup-using-lambda-function

Comment: @radhey-mishra I have added my script as gist, you can check it out https://gist.github.com/iit2011081/60e59cde32632bdbe61ade32ce1601d1